# Download Go extension to Visual Studio's 2022

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Trying to download the GoLang extension for Visual Studios 2022.  When I search for the extension it does not appear.

I tried typing in "Go" in the extension store in hopes that the GoLang coding extension would come up so I could download it.  It didn't show up.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/configure-visual-studio-code

Comment: I went to " extensions" and typed in "Go".  The extension for Go the coding language was not available.  Could it be a problem with my version?

Comment: You need install Visual Studio Code for Go extension, Not classic Visual Studio. Please carefully follow steps in the link which Pete provided.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong package.  I was simply using Visual Studios 2022 instead of VS Code, which has the correct extensions for editing in GoLang and other programming languages.

It can be download here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).